# Как добавить элемент, если чекбокс checked и убрать элемент, если он выключен

Tags: html, jquery

Есть список заказов. Выбираем элемент - он считает сумму и вставляет в нужный блок название выбранного элемента. Как сделать чтобы текст с названием добавлялся/убирался при выбранном чекбоксе? 
[Ссылка на codepen.](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/xVxgYM)

И сам код:

```
$(".price-of-package-element").change(function () {
    var count = 0,
        priceElement = $(".price-of-package-element");   
  $('#text').html('');
  for (var i = 0; priceElement[i]; ++i) {
        if (priceElement[i].checked) {
            var value = priceElement[i].value,
                title = $(this).next().text();
            count += Number(priceElement[i].value);
            $('#text').append("<div>" + title + "</div>");
         console.log(title)
        }
    }
    $('#test').text(count);

});
```

Comment: Я не уверен, но, возможно, менять свойство 'display' или 'visible'?

Comment: Нет, это список заказа. Выбираем элемент, он вносится в список под соответствующим названием. Убираем его - текст с его названием пропадает. Как в обычном прайс листе... вопрос, как убирать appended элемент при этом не затрагивая другие выбранные элементы.

Comment: испоьзовать addClass/removeClass?

Comment: можно проставить `data-атрибуты` всем элементам. при добавлении в список считывать, потом по этому же атрибуту удалять. в jquery для этого используется `.data()`